# Query writing for net transaction between accounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query in SQL to calculate the net money that is transferred between accounts. I have my test data as below in a table named Transactions.

```
Debit | From | To | Amount
---------------------------------
1     | ABC  | BBC |  $50
0     | BBC  | ABC |  $150
1     | ABC  | CBC |  $200
0     | CBC  | ABC |  $150
1     | ABC  | EBC |  $100
```

My output should be for the above test data as below:

```
From | To  | Amount
--------------------------
BBC  | ABC | $100
ABC  | CBC | $50 
ABC  | EBC | $100
```

Comment: see here to know more on how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have just updated the question. Please check and help me out .Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Debit bit,
    [From] varchar(10),
    [To] varchar(10),
    Amount int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    Debit,
    [From],
    [To],
    Amount
)
VALUES
(1, 'ABC',  'BBC', 50 ),
(0, 'BBC',  'ABC', 150),
(1, 'ABC',  'CBC', 200),
(0, 'CBC',  'ABC', 150),
(1, 'ABC',  'EBC', 100)

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT sd.[From], sd.[To], sd.Amount          
    FROM @SampleData sd
    WHERE sd.Debit = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sd.[To], sd.[From], -sd.Amount
    FROM @SampleData sd
    WHERE sd.Debit = 0
)
SELECT CASE WHEN sum(t.Amount) > 0 then t.[From] ELSe t.[To] End as [From],
      CASE when sum(t.Amount) <= 0 then t.[From] ELSe t.[To] End as [To],
      ABS(sum(t.Amount)) AS Amount
FROM temp t
GROUP BY t.[From], t.[To]
```

Returns

```
From    To  Amount
----------------------
BBC     ABC 100
ABC     CBC 50
ABC     EBC 100
```